# Plesk Downloads PHP File Rather Than Processing & Displaying It

Tags: php, plesk

If you have uploaded PHP files to your webserver with Plesk panel, you may find that when you visit the page in your browser, that the browser attempts to download the file instead of processing it and displaying it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was caused by the "Fast CGI" PHP support, which was set up by default on:

`"Website and Domains" > "Your domain name" > "Hosting Settings"`

in your Plesk panel.

Simply change it to "Apache module" and click on "Save" button.